# Сдвиг текста на странице

Tags: html, css

Смещается текст с центра экрана в лево если открыть таблицу. Видел когда-то как это фиксится, но забыл где и найти не могу сейчас. Проблема: https://youtu.be/19rC0KkkO4A

Comment: Это из-за появления скроллбара.  Есть такая штука как [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter), но поддержка не очень как по мне.